# Double Pointer to take strings causing segment fault

Tags: c, pointers, char

I want to enter string but it keeps returning segment fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char **arr;
    arr= (char** ) malloc (5);

    for(int i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(char *)malloc(10);
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++)
    {
        char ch[10];
        printf("%d",i);
        scanf("%s",ch);
        strcpy(arr[i],ch);
    }


    for(int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++)
    {
        printf("%s  ",arr[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        free (arr[i]);
    free (arr);
}
```

and also code block does not give error and runs it perfectly can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You are allocating 5 bytes, but you need `5 * sizeof(char *)` to hold 5 pointers.

Comment: Also do not cast the output of malloc.

Comment: As a general rule, you can shorten that to "Do not cast"

Comment: It's dangerous, you are trusting the user not to enter more than 9 chars.

Comment: When calling any of the memory allocation functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `scanf()` with the '%s' input format specifier, always place a max length modifier (that is one less than the actual length of the input buffer) to avoid the user overflowing the input buffer, which would result in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace** this piece of code :

```
char **arr;
arr= (char** ) malloc (5);

for(int i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    arr[i]=(char *)malloc(10);
}
```

with **this:**

```
char **arr;
arr = malloc (5*sizeof(char*));

for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
    arr[i] = malloc(10);
}
```

What goes wrong with your code is that the declaration

```
arr= (char** ) malloc (5);
```

is equivalent to

```
arr= (char** ) malloc (5 * sizeof(char));
```

which means, allocating size for 5 *characters*.
What you need to do is allocate space for 5 ***pointers to char*** for `arr`, this is why you should use `sizeof(char*)`.

You can also take a look at [this link](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/) in order to understand better what happens in memory when you allocate a double pointer.

Answer (score 0):

regarding these lines:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++)
{
    char ch[10];
    printf("%d",i);
    scanf("%s",ch);
    strcpy(arr[i],ch);
}
```

when the user enters more than 9 characters, the input buffer will be overrun.

Suggest:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++)
{
    char ch[10];
    printf("%d",i);
    scanf("%9s",ch);   <-- notice the change
    strcpy(arr[i],ch);
}
```

However, then their could be left over characters in stdin, that should be consumed and any trailing white space needs to be consumed.  Suggest:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++)
{
    char ch[10];
    printf("%d",i);
    scanf(" %9s",ch);   <-- notice the '9', notice the space
    strcpy(arr[i],ch);
    int trash;
    while( (trash = getchar() ) != EOF && '\n' != trash );
}
```